# MVC5 Identity UserManager.Update(user) not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

This is my first time using code first in MVC5 for user management. I can change passwords but I can not update the user registration. I have combed the internet and literally look at every question on this site related to UserManager.Update(user) not working.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace _100..Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual PersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual BillingInfo BillingInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual DeliveryInfo DeliveryInfo { get; set; }
        public Chapters Chapter { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class PersonalInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class BillingInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeliveryInfo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false){}

        public DbSet<PersonalInfo> PersonalInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BillingInfo> BillingInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DeliveryInfo> DeliveryInfo { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my action

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRegisteration(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I have confirmed that the user object has the updated data when it hits the action and the update method returns success but it doesn't actually update the database.

Comment: Can you post the `UserManager` declaration? What `DbContext` does this `UserManager` use?

Comment: It is passed into the constructor of my AccountController. 'code' public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

Comment: And where is it created ?

Comment: This is from the app_start/IdentityConfig.cs class created by VS             'code' var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

Comment: Everything in my AccountController uses the same UserManager but when the Update method is called it doesn't actually hit the database at all. I profiled it.

Comment: `var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
store.Context.SaveChanges();`
What happen if you `SaveChanges` explicitly after updating ?

Comment: If you override the SaveChanges method in the DbContext class (ApplicationDbContext in this case), you can set a breakpoint on this method.  From here, you could inspect the state of the entities in the change tracker to see why update statements are not being issued.  For example, if the state of the entity is Unchanged, no update statement will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several layers to this fix. First when I executed the UserManager.Update it was against the user object I received from my updateRegistration view. EF thought it was a new object and was raising an internal error "UserName already exists" and was failing but reporting success. So I had to create a dbContext and update the entity state to modified. But I learned that I also had to create a user object from the updated users ID to set the UserName or the update failed. The I found that I had to update the PasswordHash or it would be null. Then I found that I also had to update the SecurityStamp or the login process would raise an error. My Action is below.

```
 [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRegisteration(ApplicationUser UpdatedUser)
{
    var SavedUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(UpdatedUser.Id);

    try
    {
        UpdatedUser.SecurityStamp = SavedUser.SecurityStamp;
        UpdatedUser.PasswordHash = SavedUser.PasswordHash;
        UpdatedUser.UserName = SavedUser.UserName;
        UpdatedUser.Id = SavedUser.Id;
        UpdatedUser.PersonalInfo.ID = SavedUser.PersonalInfo.ID;
        UpdatedUser.BillingInfo.ID = SavedUser.BillingInfo.ID;
        UpdatedUser.DeliveryInfo.ID = SavedUser.DeliveryInfo.ID;

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        db.Entry(UpdatedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(UpdatedUser.PersonalInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(UpdatedUser.BillingInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(UpdatedUser.DeliveryInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        //            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(SavedUser);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        Exception raise = dbEx;
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                // raise a new exception nesting
                // the current instance as InnerException
                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
            }
        }
        throw raise;
    }
}
```